# Need to get unique values in array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [0] => 14
)
Array
(
    [0] => 14
)
Array
(
    [0] => 14
)
Array
(
    [0] => 14
)
Array
(
    [0] => 14
)
Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 12
)
```

I want this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 12
)
```

Here is my code:

```php
$colorarray = array();
foreach($catIds as $catid){
    $colorarray[] = $catid;
}
```

Need to get unique array values

Thanks

Comment: All those arrays to begin with, are they inside another array? Or are they entirely separate values?

Comment: Look like this is multi-dimension array - that way I answered with array flatten first

Comment: I have modified your foreach loop please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do something like this:

```
$colorarray = array();
foreach($catIds as $catid){
    if(!in_array($catid, $colorarray) {
       $colorarray[] = $catid;
    }
}
```

But also this has n*n complexity, So if your array is way too big, it might not be the most optimised solution for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `call_user_func_array` with [array-merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for flatten your array and then use [array-unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) as:

```
$res = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr);
print_r(array_unique($res)); // will give 12 and 14
```

Live example [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/HQTqB)

Or as @Progrock suggested: `$output = array_unique(array_merge(...$data));` (I like that syntax using the `...`)

Comment: Or: `$output = array_unique(array_merge(...$data));`

Answer (score 1):

You can do following to generate unique array.

```
array_unique($YOUR_ARRAY_VARIABLE, SORT_REGULAR);
```

this way only unique value is there in your array instead of duplication.

**UPDATED**

This is also one way to do same

```
<?php
 // define array 
 $a = array(1, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5); 

 // print original array 
 echo "Original Array : \n"; 
 print_r($a); 

 // remove duplicate values by using  
 // flipping keys and values 
 $a = array_flip($a); 

 // restore the array elements by again  
 // flipping keys and values. 
 $a = array_flip($a); 

 // re-order the array keys 
 $a= array_values($a); 

 // print updated array 
 echo "\nUpdated Array : \n "; 
 print_r($a); 
?>
```

[Reference link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-remove-duplicate-elements-array/)

Hope this will helps you

Comment: This answer ignores the (different) sample data in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code please check

```
$colorarray = array();
foreach($catIds as $catid){
    $colorarray[$catid] = $catid;
}
```

This will give you 100% unique values.

Comment: I recommend using this adjustment to your original code.  It has the lowest possible time complexity and makes no iterated function calls. When the loop finishes, you can call `array_values()` on `$colorarray` to remove the temporary keys.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP: Removes duplicate values from an array**

```
<?php
$fruits_list = array('Orange',  'Apple', ' Banana', 'Cherry', ' Banana');
$result = array_unique($fruits_list);
print_r($result);
?>
```

**------your case--------**

```
  $result = array_unique($catIds);
    print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a new array of all values by looping through each sub-array of the original, and then filter the result with array_unique:

```
<?php
$data =
[
    [
        0=>13
    ],
    [
        0=>13
    ],
    [
        0=>17,
        1=>19
    ]
];

foreach($data as $array)
    foreach($array as $v)
        $all_values[] = $v;

var_export($all_values);
$unique = array_unique($all_values);
var_export($unique);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 13,
    1 => 13,
    2 => 17,
    3 => 19,
  )array (
    0 => 13,
    2 => 17,
    3 => 19,
  )
```